# Django Redux Registration Incorrect Password / Username when it is correct

Tags: python, html, django, web

I created an application and am using Django Redux Registration to handle authentication and creation of users, but I am not able to login unless it is a super user I created through the console. When I click "Register" again with the same username is says the name is already taken, but cannot login despite the password being correct. I can still login with superusers but nothing else.

Settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for yoloq project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p(n=h+*3#9&c)qyyaa^fz3d0(w&hkzqr9p!k9y8@uld*0bz1is'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'SearchGame',
    'registration',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'yoloq.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'yoloq.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'EST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

#DJANGO REGISTRATION REDUX SETTINGS
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="post" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                </form>

        <p>Not  a member? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So far from some research I believe it has something to do with my registration form not saving the password so Django is giving it a random password despite having a password field. Any ideas how to change this? thank you.

Comment: Did you override djano registration redux's form ? check : https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Registration Redux Registers users but does not set them as active users. Hence when you try to login the Redux at the backend makes verification and allows login only if the active flag is set. 
As the superuser is set with default active flag when created through createsuperuser command he is allowed to log in.

So in order to make the registered users to be able to login you need to set their active flag to true through admin panel or let them use the activation link if you are sending them for email verification.